# Hive explode each JSON element in JSON array to rows

Tags: json, hive, hiveql

I have neted JSON data like:

```
{"body":{"metrics":[{"a":1,"a1":1.1,"properties":{"propA":"name","propB":"age"}},{"b":2}]}}
{"body":{"metrics":[{"c":3}]}}
```

I can use `select get_json_object(get_json_object(columnA,'$.Body'),'$.metrics') from...` to extracted nested json arrays like:

```
[{"a":1,"a1":1.1,"a2":{"propA":"name","propB":"age"}},{"b":2}]
[{"c":3}]
```

I want to convert them into rows like:

```
{"a":1,"a1":1.1,"a2":{"propA":"name","propB":"age"}}
{"b":2}
{"c":3}
```

It seems the array returned by `get_json_object` is string and when I use `later view` it always says：
`UDFArgumentException explode() takes an array or a map as a parameter`

Length of each array is uncertain and I do not have permit to upload jar files to active new udf or serde  clases. How to achieve this...

Comment: Are you saying that this is STRING: [{"a":1},{"b":2}] ?

Comment: @leftjoin Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure... It's returned by `get_json_object` and it looks like string..  Or do you have any better idea?  Btw, I just modified the original question post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your json is in a table `test`. You can use below query to get the desired output:

```sql
select m.* from test s
LATERAL view explode(split(regexp_replace(get_json_object(value,'$.body.metrics'),'^\\[|]$',''), ',(?!")')) m
```